# HTTP vs. HTTPS - The coding point of view

Tags: http, networking, https

To send an HTTP request through a socket to a server, i would do something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
User-agent: SomeBot
...
```

How would you go about programmatically defining an HTTPS request? I'm not looking for any programming language specific answer, something that teaches me the essence of HTTPS.

**My research:**

When i goto `https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=sg7MUvKgGoX_rAeKxoGIDg&ved=0CBQQ1S4` this is what i get:

```
GET https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=sg7MUvKgGoX_rAeKxoGIDg&ved=0CBQQ1S4 HTTP/1.1
:host: www.google.co.in
x-chrome-variations: COy1yQEIlLbJAQiftskBCKS2yQEIqLbJAQiptskBCL62yQEI8YPKAQ==
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36
:path: /webhp?tab=ww&ei=sg7MUvKgGoX_rAeKxoGIDg&ved=0CBQQ1S4
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
:version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: PREF=ID=c032cbb31701d0d8:U=3a8fed312bb2ee57:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1374381891:LM=1376055657:S=BooLSkeTxOsbOYls; NID=67=HDIT9zwo-KKhljgRnJMz4u_5L_qpj3FvsN9Y47dWZmByQRS4N8QYs64IcEjFYphs6YpbrmvgsejwaL5YwxzbkY_qYaKU7wBfDA9N955NznF7IIyeHxcQ5UX8Dm999AElAKdkyswNbwUx1WJZo5vEuIaqC4Hdw4AkjsdwmFjY4ujPiEAj72z93QpCLleM-NXOK8N5YWn8DqiteGrEZUQ3FdPK3vkfDet_GF3CcBnkiYWxXON6R8Kum8BWaJGtm9h5dA; SID=DQAAANQAAAB2hOHWGXo76aWm_lgruhW0NH_zbU26rK7YMM_uiyMRvIBoyiEb3Gn_j2AhtmM4v6a74DinFMAOIjq5N4g4JcAAXaMEXz1dUz8MVup_nt1udNM0hpvybeWPxE1xK8rvdL2ra9moRW58jRzzA0HdpmkrH_t2ZIQ7GhqJlxp6lOS_jfvmeeb3REYFp6Q08hRYvCRDmhYFQ7NSt_Ua_3EWu4d_o125kvZ0x0bwm7JDKEcO3S-b6SJ4KnAGIWYjQKPdirgIFEUm1vApvIr4hoa4Z01rBt9YTmhwdEG5KvJmjusPkQ; HSID=AoEbPqSO97tEXhBOd; SSID=Abkp9uP00vi4wX19_; APISID=idPvNkfOQ-W9vefw/AjRgJIuDHZMDnME-B; SAPISID=5UH5pOlPn4c_31En/AcwfUulAqos_McwmH
:scheme: https
referer: https://www.google.co.in/
:method: GET
```

I see that it is pretty understandable, yet slightly alien...

Comment: HTTPS is just HTTP inside of SSL/TLS. It's not really a protocol.

Comment: i know that, my question is about the specification of HTTPS

Comment: What you see in your second example hides a huge amount of detail regarding the preceding negotiation and key exchange between the browser and the server; http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246 0- its just an example of an HTTP request travelling over an established SSL connection.

Comment: is there any sort of official specification of HTTPS?

Comment: The RFC in the link is the definitive specification

Comment: no, i dont mean it in that way, what i mean is i want a place that can teach me about all the necessary headers, and basically, the differnce  in the protocol definition of HTTP and HTTPs, i know that HTTPS is secure HTTP and the differences of the technology, but i want to know the differences in programming it

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: The *only* difference is SSL. HTTPS is just the name given to HTTP over SSL/TLS.

Comment: Well there is none, as @Blender said HTTP is the same, in the case of HTTPS it just happens to be travelling over an SSL/TLS connection instead of an unencrypted socket connection

Comment: So reallythe only difference is the port no. To which you connect???

Comment: An HTTP request may include a port number but it does not care about it: HTTP is a protocol that operates *after* a network connection has been established, it does not care if you issue a "GET /blah" via a "normal" socket connection or a much more complex TLS/SSL connection.